# Macgap making the File > new work and allow several windows

Tags: xcode, cordova, macgap

Just started using macgap1. How can I make the File > New in the menuBar work to open a second window?

I managed to bind the `File` > `New` in xcode, linking it to a property in `AppDelegate.m` and create an alert, so that part works, but not I don't know how to make it generate a second window.